# Scala dynamic list sorting

Tags: scala, sorting

I'm looking for a clean way of dynamically sorting a list with the following requirements.

```
case class Person(name: String, middleName:Option[String], age:Integer)
```

Now sorting that is pretty straight forward however if this sort is driven off a UI where a user would do column sorting and the parameters passed back to the server would simply be the column name. Any suggestions to dynamically create this sorting capability?

Thanks in advance

**Updated:

```
val sortByName = (p :Person) => p.name
val sortByMiddleName = (p: Person) => p.middleName

val mySortMap = Map("name" -> sortByName, "middleName" -> sortByMiddleName)

val sorted = persons.sortBy(mySortMap("name"))
```

** Update #2

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._

type PersonSorter = (Person, Person) => Boolean
val sortByName: PersonSorter = (x:Person, y:Person) => x.name < y.name
// Implicits import takes care of the Option here...
val sortByMiddleName: PersonSorter = (x:Person, y:Person) => x.middleName < y.middleName

val sortingMap: PersonSorter = Map[String, PersonSorter]("name" -> sortByName, "middleName" -> sortByMiddleName)
```

(Excluded age, but it's the exact same thing)

Now when I have my list, I can easily just do this.

```
persons.sortWith(sortingMap("name"))
```

Where "name" is a parameter string passed in from the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
scala> val alice = Person("Alice", None, 20)
alice: Person = Person(Alice,None,20)

scala> val bob = Person("Bob", None, 21)
bob: Person = Person(Bob,None,21)

scala> val charlie = Person("Charlie", None, 18)
charlie: Person = Person(Charlie,None,18)

scala> val persons = List(alice, bob, charlie)
persons: List[Person] = List(Person(Alice,None,20), Person(Bob,None,21), Person(Charlie,None,18))

scala> persons.sortBy(p => (p.age, p.name))
res5: List[Person] = List(Person(Charlie,None,18), Person(Alice,None,20), Person(Bob,None,21))

scala> persons.sortBy(p => (p.name, p.age))
res6: List[Person] = List(Person(Alice,None,20), Person(Bob,None,21), Person(Charlie,None,18))
```

To dynamically sort by parameters you can define you own sort functions based on the parameters passed as input. So you could write a function that returns a function that is passed into `persons.sortBy`. That function passed in is the sorting function which could by `sortByAge` for example. It's the same idea if you need to sort by two or more parameters.

```
scala> val sortByAge = (p :Person) => p.age
sortByAge: Person => Integer = <function1>

scala> persons.sortBy(sortByAge)
res9: List[Person] = List(Person(Charlie,None,18), Person(Alice,None,20), Person(Bob,None,21))
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant, I managed this part okay.  This is under the assumption you know what you want to sort by.  If a query parameter comes through a request as sortBy=age then I'd need the sorting to happen on age, next request could be sortBy=name.

Comment: @Colin See the updated answer. `sortBy` takes a function to do the sorting so you can define and pass your own function to it based on the parameters given as input.

Comment: @Brain, thanks for the updated answer.  I was hoping I could do something like I am doing in the updated question.  I'll have to do it slightly different then.  Thanks, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
case class Person(name: String, id: Int)
  def sort[T](list: List[T])(compare: (T, T) => Boolean): List[T] = {
    list.sortWith(compare)
  }
  
  
  val list = List(Person("P2", 1), Country("P1", 10))
    val rl = sort(list)((a, b) => a.name < b.name)
```

This is plain and simple